# Blender rendering slower with second GPU enabled - RTX3070+Quadro M4000

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have an RTX 3070 and a Quadro M4000. Blender shows the (Display) next to the M4000 device in preferences and in task manager the M4000 is listed as GPU 0 and the 3070 GPU 1. Not sure how to reverse that. I have my primary display attached to the 3070 and a secondary to the M4000. Certain applications like Madmapper seem to require the primary display be attached to the rendering GPU so my Idea was to leave the primary on the 3070 and have the M4000 handle secondary display and projectors in addition to providing additional rendering power to Blender.

With the M4000 disabled in Blender it renders 2 seconds faster than enabled.

In task manager I can see the usage of both cards go to 100% at times and then either card will drop to 0 periodically, almost like the issue is the cards struggling to work together.

In the Nvidia Control Panel i have the 3070 set as the OpenGL Rendering GPU.

I tried installing the Quadro driver, but then learned you can only use one driver at a time and reverted to the Studio driver for the 3070 to work. At least I can still use the Desktop Manager application that requires a Quadro card..

Anyone have any insight on this?
Thanks

Comment: It's a known bug and it's being worked on.

Comment: Do you know more about it or where I can find forum posts about it? Not sure what exactly to search.

Comment: See [T87836](https://developer.blender.org/T87836) for a complete list of tasks related to GPU scheduling.  The best place to look for discussions like this is either [devtalk](https://devtalk.blender.org) or [developer](https://developer.blender.org)